# is there no need to save state for the IOS 4.0 multitasking support scenario?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, multitasking

I getting a little confused about when one needs to save state for an iPhone app.  In particular for the scenario where one's Iphone IOS version supports multitasking, and when you come back to it, it does appear to be in the same state (for my simple app anyway).

Question - Can you clarify how the "need to save state for an iPhone app", and the multitasking support play together.

Hopefully the response can help clarify aspects such as:

1. For the multitasking support scenario (when a user doesn't explicitly terminate the application), is there any need at all to save state?  Or does IOS do it for you (which it kind of appears it does for my simple app).
2. If the answer to 1 is YES, then at what point do you really need to save state then?
3. If the answer to 1 is NO, then exactly what data/state do you lose versus not-lose when IOS does keep your application "running" in the background?

thanks

Comment: Save state **whenever you can**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1A.  Yes.  Because...

1B.  You don't know.  The OS usually saves state on newer devices, but this is not guaranteed, and will not always happen.  On older devices the OS won't save state.

2A.  Even if the answer to 1B. is YES, the OS could still delete your app's state to save memory.  So you still need to save any state you don't want potentially lost after your app is suspended.

3A.  Your app may lose track of time (from NSTimer ticks, etc.) if it doesn't check the clock on resume.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do to support multitasking is compile against 4.0 or greater.

You should save application data to a file, but IOS will keep all your views and viewcontrollers in memory and will resume where it left off when the app is switched back.

Keep in mind, that when your app is in the background, IOS can fully terminate it at anytime in an attempt to re-claim memory so make sure your user data is persisted.

Comment: Since iOS can eject your app from memory when it's in the background, never saving state means that _sometimes_ it will restore as it was when the home button was pressed and sometimes it won't. This might be confusing. Best to save state when your app goes into the background.

Answer (score 2):

Normally with multitasking the application continues to run and there would be no need to explicitly save the application's state. However, if the phone is running low on memory, it may very well decide to dump your application while it's in background mode.

For phone's that do not have background mode (e.g. the 3G) you would always need to save state.

Bottom line, you'll want to save state whenever going into background in the event the application is removed from memory later. You would only have to read it back on a re-launch, not upon coming back from background.

As far as "what state" needs to be saved, it really depends on your particular application. Perhaps the selected tab or navigation? A lot depends on user expectation of not losing any work.